# The lead has pinched right out

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XVI, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_16)

Passage 251

> “This is the end of me commercially. I give up; my nerve is gone. I suppose I ought to be glad; for we're through the court. I don't know as ever I knew how, and I'm sure I don't remember. If it pans out—the wreck, I mean—we'll go to Europe, and live on the interest of our money. No more work for me. I shake when people speak to me. I have gone on, hoping and hoping, and working and working, and **the lead has pinched right out**. I want to lie on my back in a garden and read Shakespeare and E. P. Roe. Don't suppose it's cowardice, Loudon. I'm a sick man. Rest is what I must have. I've worked hard all my life; I never spared myself; every dollar I ever made, I've coined my brains for it. I've never done a mean thing; I've lived respectable, and given to the poor. Who has a better right to a holiday than I have? And I mean to have a year of it straight out; and if I don't, I shall lie right down here in my tracks, and die of worry and brain trouble.

This wording troubles me. In particular *pinch out* is a problem for me. There are some hints as to *geology* and *plants* but that doesn't work here in my opinion. And the word *lead* is a problem as well. It seems to mean the *lead* with *sounding* but I can't nail it in this context.

Comment: It is a mining metaphor.  A lead is a cut made to get access to a seam of ore. When the ore exposed  "pinches" it grows narrower, and when it "pinches out" it has narrowed down to nothing. Compare "peter out".

Comment: He's saying "I'm used up, depleted, I feel as though I've got nothing left in me".

Comment: Yet again, you're being distracted by [an outdated usage.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vein+petered+out%2Cvein+pinched+out&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) There's merit in learning idiomatic ***peter out***, because that's used metaphorically in a wide variety of contexts today. But not ***pinch out***, which today only really exists in the sense of *removing dead / unwanted parts of plants*, and more recently the thumb+finger gesture used on touch screens to zoom the display. This really isn't relevant to "learning English".

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP is caught in a catch-22, not knowing whether what is being asked about is current usage or not.  If it's current usage and the question is posed on english.stackexchange.com the question is sent here.  If it's not current usage, it's off-topic here.  I don't think answering questions on older usages is going to open the floodgates for such questions here.

Comment: @TimR: I never supposed the floodgates would open. When this OP first started asking questions about unusual phrasing in *The Wrecker*, I thought I was advising ***him*** against using such an outdated text as a vehicle for learning English. Partly because it can't be much fun trying to read a book when you have to keep looking many things up, *and* some of the things you're looking for are so obscure ordinary learners dictionaries are no help. But mainly because what's being learnt is of limited relevance. Obviously this OP doesn't care about that, but it's potentially  distracting to others.

Comment: TimR is right - I'm caught in a catch-22. My mother tongue isn't English hence I'm not able to realize if the wording is dated or obsolete or not. I don't like FumbleFingers' permanent nagging. If you don't like to answer the question don't do it. If you worry about the learners here please add your comment regarding the current usage - that will help and will be a positive and extra benefit; I'd be pleased about that.

Comment: I should apologize for the "nagging". Per previous comment, I fully accept that you don't need to accept my advice. I'm only really commenting to warn *other* learners that it's probably not in their best interests to take too much notice of the answers to many of your questions. Without such a warning, many learners might be misled into thinking ***peter out*** and ***pinch out*** are "equivalent", and I can easily imagine that *of the two*, they'd be more likely to remember the latter, simply because it's a known verb in other contexts. But it wouldn't work in conversational contexts today!

Comment: There is another word: *crop out* that fits the context. When you compare *pinch out* with *crop out*, *pinch out* performs better.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vein+crop+out%2Cvein+pinched+out&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20 - Ok, I see *crop out* has a different meaning.

Comment: @TimR Your top comment would make a good answer

Comment: Coming back to **pinch out** I'm wondering if it couldn't be **a specific, geological (technical) term** all the same. (when reading FumbleFingers' *There's merit in learning idiomatic peter out, because that's **used metaphorically in a wide variety of contexts today***). **OED**has this: **pinch out,** in pinch, v., intransitive. **Mining and Geology. Of a vein or deposit of ore, or a stratum: to contract in volume, to become gradually thinner; to pinch out: to…** - oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=pinchout

Comment: Another link: https://www.google.de/books/edition/Arabian_Plate_and_Surroundings_Geology_S/YVKsDwAAQBAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=pinches+out&pg=PA83&printsec=frontcover - page 83, left text / last line but one - "pinches out" - Regarding **lead** **OED** has this: lead, n.² **Mining. = lode, n. Also figurative**./lead, n.²  **Mining. Gold-mining. An alluvial deposit of gold along the bed of an ancient river**. Also deep-lead, great-blue-lead (see quots.).

Comment: Damaged link of the last but one comment: https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=pinch-out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**to pinch out** in this context is a mining metaphor. A **lead** is a cut made to get access to a seam of ore. When the ore exposed "pinches" it grows narrower, and when it "pinches out" it has narrowed down to nothing. Compare "peter out".

He's saying that he's done with working and wants to stop. It's analogous to someone saying "I've run out of steam", with the meaning that he hasn't got it in him to persevere any longer in an endeavor.