# pinch out vs. peter out

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

I would like to know what phrasing is the **correct geological technical term** for a **lode** or **ore vein** that grows narrower and narrower till it narrows down to nothing - is it **pinch out** or **peter out**?

(besides, does it have to be *geological technical term* or *geologically technical term* or just *geological term*?)

Related:  [The lead has pinched right out](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343644/the-lead-has-pinched-right-out/343656#343656)

> Yet again, you're being distracted by an outdated usage. There's merit in learning idiomatic peter out, because that's used metaphorically in a wide variety of contexts today. But not pinch out, which today only really exists in the sense of removing dead / unwanted parts of plants, and more recently the thumb+finger gesture used on touch screens to zoom the display. This really isn't relevant to "learning English". – FumbleFingers

Comment: You'd probably be better asking a geologist rather than an English language learner - maybe on https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Things peter out; they do not pinch out. So, FF is right. And it's not just geological either. Anything that extends over a distance can **peter out**. A road or path, for instance. In fact, pinch out is not at all common.

Comment: Also, his voice petered out over the radio as we were no longer able to get the station.

Comment: What is pinch out in geology? 1. n. [Geology] A type of stratigraphic trap. **The termination by thinning or tapering out ("pinching out")** of a reservoir against a nonporous sealing rock creates a favorable geometry to trap hydrocarbons, particularly if the adjacent sealing rock is a source rock such as a shale. [Google linked to The Energy Glossary](https://glossary.slb.com/en/terms/p/pinch-out#:~:text=1.%20n.%20%5BGeology%5D,rock%20such%20as%20a%20shale.)

Comment: I think this question is just pointlessly trying to marshal support for disagreeing with my assertion as reproduced above. My comment specifically included [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vein+petered+out%2Cvein+pinched+out&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) showing that ***vein pinched out*** was twice as common as ***vein petered out*** a century ago, but the latter is twice as common as the former today. And obviously the word ***vein*** means they're ***all*** for the mining / geological context. Usage ***has*** changed over time!

Comment: @FF - If I offended you I apologize. I didn't mean to, but the whole discussion of the cited question/link confused me. So I just would like to know what I say in this question here. But I do accept what you said in the cited question and I do agree with you *peter out* fits better into that cited context **nowadays**. I think I did understand your argument and comment correctly :).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about a technical *use* of a term, and not about learning English.

Comment: I would say learning technical terms is learning too, and in this case it isn't only learning a technical term but also to learn to distinguish or  differentiate between a common and a technical usage - that's important as well in my opinion, isn't it.

Comment: I'll delete this question because neither of the reasons - 1) "This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question" - and 2) "or provide more context" - is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct geological term of art is **pinch out**.

Here's some text from some geology modeling software called *Seequent*:

> *Improved pinch-out behaviour* – Previously, if a drillhole did not contain valid logging it was ignored for pinch-out creation, meaning vein models passed straight through drillhole traces. An additional control is provided to the user to choose whether the vein should pinch out on an empty trace (a hole where no lithology has been logged) or continue through it.
>
> *Export/Import of Bulk Vein Edits* – it is common that manual editing of vein components is required to produce the vein model you want. Until now, vein edits were only accessible from within the vein model, which made it difficult to recreate a vein from scratch, or even keep a record of edits that had been made. It is now possible to export all user-made vein edits to file, using the Export Vein Edits option on the vein object. This dumps all user made vein edits for segments, midpoints and pinch-outs to a text file.